# Adding extra data to a Variable

Tags: php, variables

Right now, my code plucks out only one value using Mysql. So I thought I might aswell add each found result to a variable, however I dont know how to do this.

This must be a *very* basic question, but I cant find a answer for it

```
    echo '<table border="1">';
  echo "<tr><td><b>Surname</b></td><td><b>Title/Name</b></td><td><b>Numbers</b></td><td><b>Telephone</b></td><td><b>Edit</b></td><td><b>Del</b></td></tr>\n";
  while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $Surname = $row["Surname"];
  $Title = $row["TitleName"];
  $Email = $row["Email"];
  $Telephone = $row["Telephone"];
  $id = $row["id"];
  $MooringNumbers = $row['Number'];  
  $Assignedto['AssignedTo'];  
  }
  $MooringQuery = "select * FROM mooring WHERE AssignedTo='$id'";
  $MooringResult = mysql_query($MooringQuery) or die("Couldn't execute query");
  while ($row1= mysql_fetch_array($MooringResult)) {
  $AssignedTo = $row1["AssignedTo"];
  $MooringNumbers = $row1["Number"];
    echo '<tr><td>' .$Surname.'</td><td>'.$Title.'</td><td>'.$MooringNumbers . '</td><td>'.$Telephone.'</td><td>' . '<a href="rlayCustomerUpdtForm.php?id='.$id.'">[EDIT]</a></td>'.'<td>'. '<a href="deleteCustomer.php?id='.$id.'">[x]</a></td>'. '</tr>';   
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and/or show some code. It sounds like you want to use arrays...

Comment: Just an idea, but if you're trying to get the total of a set of results, you might want to use the SQL SUM function - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: Posted my code, it only grabs one value for the $MooringNumbers Variable, however there are more than one result which should be showing.

Comment: Is the answer as simple as putting everything after the `while` loop into the `while` loop?

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe: Are there more than one which the same `AssignedTo` id?

Comment: @Felix King That was part of previous code, I forgot to remove that. What happens is that I have 2 tables one with Moorings and one with customers. The moorings are assosiated to the customers with $AssignedTo. The Mooring(s) should only be picked out if the  $id matchs $AssignedTo

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

You can iterate over `$rows` using `foreach`:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

In case you use PDO for your database access you could also use the `fetchAll()` method on the result object which returns an array similar to `$rows` in the above code.

Comment: Thanks for doing this but, I do not know how to implement this into my code, I will edit my question to include the code I currently use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but the answer sounds as simple as putting the last few lines into the outer `while` loop:

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $Surname = $row["Surname"];
  $Title = $row["TitleName"];
  $Email = $row["Email"];
  $Telephone = $row["Telephone"];
  $id = $row["id"];
  $MooringNumbers = $row['Number'];  
  $Assignedto['AssignedTo'];  
  $MooringQuery = "select * FROM mooring WHERE AssignedTo='$id'";
  $MooringResult = mysql_query($MooringQuery) or die("Couldn't execute query");
  while ($row1= mysql_fetch_array($MooringResult)) {
    $AssignedTo = $row1["AssignedTo"];
    $MooringNumbers = $row1["Number"];
    echo '<tr><td>' .$Surname.'</td><td>'.$Title.'</td><td>'.$MooringNumbers . '</td><td>'.$Telephone.'</td><td>' . '<a href="rlayCustomerUpdtForm.php?id='.$id.'">[EDIT]</a></td>'.'<td>'. '<a href="deleteCustomer.php?id='.$id.'">[x]</a></td>'. '</tr>';   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that returns ONLY the customer with the Mooring Number.